# How to get selected items from Webpy dropdown

Tags: drop-down-menu, web.py

I'm new to the Webpy. Currently, I have trouble to retrieve the items selected in the Dropdown menu and I haven't seen any help on it. Could anyone show me how to solve the problem?

Thanks

My python server:

```
import web
import pdb
from matching_tester import *

def make_text(string):
    return string

class tutorial:
    def GET(self):
        form = my_form()
        return render.tutorial(my_form(), "Your text goes here.")
    def POST(self):
        form = my_form()
        form.validates()
        s = form.d.Devices
        print s
        return make_text(s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = ('/', 'tutorial')
    render = web.template.render('templates/')

    app = web.application(urls, globals())

    my_form = web.form.Form(
                    web.form.Dropdown('Devices', [('1', 'iPhone 4'), 
                                                  ('2', 'iPhone 4S'), 
                                                  ('3', 'iPhone 5')], 
                                                  web.form.notnull,
                                      **{'multiple':None, 'size': 4}),
                    web.form.Dropdown('Country', [('1', 'All'), 
                                                  ('2', 'US'), 
                                                  ('3', 'JP')],        
                                                 web.form.notnull,
                                      **{'multiple':None, 'size': 4})
                    )
    app.run()
```

My HTML:

```
=== tutorial.html ===
$def with (form, text)
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Python and AJAX tutorial for beginners with webpy and jQuery</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/tutorial.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                                jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                                jQuery(".button").click(function() {
                                        var input_string = $$("input#textfield").val();
                                        jQuery.ajax({
                                                type: "POST",
                                                data: {textfield : input_string},
                                                success: function(data) {                                                    jQuery('#foo').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1500);
                                                },

                                                });
                                        return false;
                                        });
                                });
                        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br>
        <form class="form" method="post">
        $:form.render()
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="send"/>
        </form>
        <br><br>
        <span id="foo">$text</span>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: no matter what I select, print s will give None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're working too hard:

Your python code is good. Your HTML is okay, but the embedded javascript is the problem.

Specifically, your call to `var input_string = ...` is bad (and unnecessary). You don't have an input element with id `textfield`. No matter, you don't need it.

In your ajax call, you're sending bad data, the value of textfield. Instead, just serialize the form and send that info.:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: jQuery('form').serialize(),  // <-- Here
    success: function (data) {
        jQUery('#foo').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1500);
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was spending hours on it. Just one more question. 

So far, if I select multiple entries, I only got one at the python script. How I can get an array of inputs from the dropdown?

Comment: @NanMa Honestly, I find the `Form` code not worth the trouble: write your own.  Form.Dropdown only support single entry. Docs say, "mutually exclusive input for lists (select and options)".   However, the Browser will send multiple results, and you can read them in you POST, but you need to use something like `device_list = web.input(Devices=[]).Devices`. `web.input()` always returns user input dict. By saying `Devices=[]` you're telling `web.input()` that Devices is list type, rather than a singleton. I don't know if the built-in Dropdown validator will work correctly with lists.

Comment: Thank you for the the comment. That was exactly what I did last night. I commented out the Dropdown from python and did it at HTML.

Moving forward, do you know any other good python framework that is good for the web? The reason I picker webpy was due to i have a large portion of backend processing written in python

Thank  you

Comment: I use web.py because it lets me write the site python. Using Django, etc, means you're writing in Django, etc. (which, to me, means you learn another language and then have to debug what __it's__ doing to figure out why something isn't working.)